# Is there anyway to make BeatifulSoup 4 to recognize html 4 unmarked self-closing tags correctly?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

It seems that when there is a input tag which doesn't mark itself as self-closed (i think this is valid in HTML 4), beautiful soup 4 can not recognize it correctly

for example:

```
>>> s=BeautifulSoup("<p><input type='hidden' value='abc'><br></p>")
>>> s.find('input')
<input type="hidden" value="abc"><br/></input>
```

so I'm wondering is there anyway to fix this

Comment: is `lxml` an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about `BeautifulSoup`, but if using `lxml` is an option (which I do recommend), it can parse `input` correctly. Also you can set `method='xml'` for rendering self-closing node. So in your example, it will be:

```
In [8]: import lxml

In [9]: tree = lxml.html.fromstring("<p><input type='hidden' value='abc'><br></p>")

In [10]: lxml.html.tostring(tree)
Out[10]: '<p><input type="hidden" value="abc"><br></p>'

In [11]: lxml.html.tostring(tree.find('input'), method='xml')
Out[11]: '<input type="hidden" value="abc"/>'
```

See above, because `lxml` parser doesn't use regex to parse the nodes, it can more precisely capture the `input` node correctly.

And by setting the `method='xml'` you can then render that node in self-closing manner.

Comment: wow, this remind me that BeautifulSoup support lxml as parser. I mistook lxml for a pure xml parser. The result is impressive when using lmxl as parser for BeautifulSoup, much better then python's built-in html parser when dealing with some ugly old html documents. Thank you for your hint

Comment: @adamhj, Yes once you mentioned I do recall `lxml` has a **soupparser** a like probably for use with **BeautifulSoup**, good call and glad it helps :)